# Angular2 - how to dynamic insert the component that were created?

Tags: angular

I have created some components through the code like:

```
resolveCom(com: any, viewContain: ViewContainerRef): ComponentRef<any> {
        let comFac = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(com)
        let newCom: ComponentRef<any> = viewContain.createComponent(comFac)
        newCom.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
        return newCom
   }
```

And I dynamic create some compoennts and save them into the array:

```
let newCom: ComponentRef<any> = this.resolveCom(item, viewContain)
saveCom[key].push(newCom)
```

The view can show the components that were created.Now i want to hide or show these components but i don't want to destroy them and recreate them. 
I saved them just now,can i dynamic insert the component that i save to the view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access the element using `location.nativeElement` and then use it to set attributes or properties

```
newCom.location.nativeElement.hidden = true
```

or

```
this.renderer.setElementProperty(newCom.location.nativeElement, 'hidden', true);
```

Comment: But the `hidden` attributes seems wasn't supported on IE10 -

Comment: That was meant as an example. You can use `setElementAttribute()` or `setElementClass()` instead, and add `[hidden] { display: none; }` to your global CSS to get better browser support. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html

Comment: enn..what should I do when I want to create a compoennt with some params?  Then the new compoennt can opera the params.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Perhaps `newCom.instance.someProp = someValue;` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 also shows how to do that.

Comment: the `someValue` is the data of one component,and i get it,then when i create a new component i pass this data to it by `newCom.instance.someProp = someValue;` , but when the new component change the `someProp`,the `somaValue` dosen't changed? why

Comment: Thats expected behavior. You can add an observable to the compinent and subscribe to it. `newCom.instance.somePropChange.subscribe(...)`

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service shows examples how to use observables.

Comment: I create a new component, and then i want to dynamically add some Directives' selector to the this new component's template and make it works.  Like `render.setElementAttribute(newCom.location,"my directive's selector", "")`. So how can i make it works well with my directive?

Comment: Ditectives are not instantiated for dynamically added attributes, only when added ststically to a components template.